# How to use adminlte modal in laravel?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, bootstrap-modal, adminlte

In my Laravel project , I use AdminLTE and I want to use modals in it.
all part of AdminLTE works great. but, I can't use modals. I don't know how to use it. should I add any js code for it?

scripts:

```
<script src="{{asset('bower_components/jquery/jquery.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('bower_components/admin-lte/dist/js/adminlte.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('bower_components/select2/dist/js/select2.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('bower_components/select2/dist/js/select2.full.js')}}"></script>
```

I want to have some thing like this : https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/UI/modals.html

Comment: Why do you use CoreUI documentation for AdminLTE features? One is Bootstrap 4 and the other is Bootstrap 3.

Comment: ok, I have made a mistake. I correct it. but still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you loading your CSS correctly? Also double check Bootstrap versions.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, there was problem in css loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had mistake in css loading and also I didn't add modal's js file :

```
<script src="{{asset('bower_components/bootstrap/js/modal.js')}}"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not Related to Laravel As long as it concerns The modals and Design 
so now you have To Check your console For any Error And see If there is any error on console for that modal and if not you have to check any kind of js for modal or bootstrap for modal and in the end you can check from this link for cdn usage of modal plugin for bootstrap :

```
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-modal
```

and if not finally check the atrribute of modal and bottuns :

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

this is an example paste this code and check if its working on your project .

Comment: still doesn't show any thing and there isn't any error in console.

Comment: @HaniyeShadman Did You add The Example Code in Your project ?? and this example modal doesnt work too ??

Comment: Yes, it just show the modal content without clicking.

Comment: @HaniyeShadman then Its the problem with bootstrap loading the modal plugin can u copy the  part that you include the resources for js and css ??

Comment: Thanks for replying. I had mistake in path.

Comment: @HaniyeShadman thanks consider acceping the Answer Or Post The right answer for other people mistake to use this